# M and N are topological manifolds then so is M x N

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Question:
>   If M and N are topological manifolds, then so is M \times X wih the product topology.

My question is to show that $M \times N$ is locally euclidean.

Attempt:

M and N are both locally euclidean.
So there exists an open set m in M containing element x in M that is homeomorphic to some open set $V_{1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$.
So there exists an open set m in M containing element x in M that is homeomorphic to some open set $V_{2} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Indeed,
$f_{1}:m\rightarrow v_{1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$

$f_{2}:n\rightarrow v_{2}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$

The cartesian product ensures the map

$f_{1} \times f_{2}:m \times n \rightarrow v_{1} \times v_{2}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$

$\left ( x,y \right ) \mapsto \left [ f_{1}\left ( x \right ),f_{2}\left ( y \right ) \right ]$

It now suffices to show that the open set $v_{1} \times v_{2} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is homeomorphic to some open set $\bar{v}  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{i}$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$

I am unable to determine the homeomorphism.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, by mapping $((x_1,\dots,x_m),(y_1,\dots,y_n))$ to $(x_1,\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n)$.

Comment: My analysis is very shaky. Can you prove why the homeomorphism holds?

Comment: How you prove that depends on how you define the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (there are several equivalent ways).

Comment: @Mathematicing: It looks like you need to read about the product topology. There is a good chapter in Munkres topology book on this topic.